# SQL Server printf

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000

Is there a printf-like function in Sql Server? I want the same features as the RAISERROR function, but instead of throwing an error, or printing a message, I want to **write it in a varchar**, because my ERP won't let me handle the error messages.

This is SQL Server 2000.

Actual working example with RAISERROR:

```
declare @name varchar(10)
set @name = 'George'

RAISERROR ('Hello %s.', 10, 1, 'George')
```

prints `Hello George`

What I'm looking for:

```
declare @name varchar(10), @message varchar(50)
set @name = 'George'

SET @message = printf('Hello %s.', 'George')
return @message
```

This would return `Hello George`

Comment: Most tools don't treat messages returned by `RAISERROR` with a severity of 10 or lower as an actual error - does yours?

Comment: No, it doesn't, but it still won't let me handle the message, that is, get it into a variable and not display it to the user.

Comment: Have you tested that it allows you to access `PRINT` messages? If so `RAISERROR` with severity 0 should be the same AFAIK. According to erland sommarskog [PRINT is just a shortcut for
RAISERROR with level 0.](http://dbaspot.com/forums/sqlserver-programming/270658-qa-messages.html)

Comment: I don't want to print it. I want to write its value into a variable. I'll edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have a limited number of format strings, and are able to add them to sysmessages (via [sp_addmessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addmessage-transact-sql)), you can use [FORMATMESSAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql):

> Like the RAISERROR statement, FORMATMESSAGE edits the message by substituting the supplied parameter values for placeholder variables in the message. For more information about the placeholders allowed in error messages and the editing process, see RAISERROR.

---

The below would be a valid answer for SQL Server 2005 or later, but unfortunately, the OP is seeking a solution for SQL Server 2000:

---

It's ugly, and an abuse of Try/Catch and `RAISERROR`:

```
declare @message varchar(50)

begin try
    RAISERROR('Hello %s',16,1,'george')
end try
begin catch
    set @message = ERROR_MESSAGE()
end catch

print @message
```

Comment: IIRC, try catch was introduced in Sql Server 2005. But that would have been awesome.

Comment: @DonkeyMaster - you're right, sorry. I don't think there's a way to intercept the error message in 2000, and `RAISERROR` is the only function I know of within SQL Server that has these printf style formatting options.

Comment: @DonkeyMaster - I think I've found the closest fit for 2000, but it does require changing the state of the server, so would only work if the number of format strings required are small and fixed.

Comment: @Damien - `xp_sprintf` does the job on 2000 AFAIK.

Comment: @Martin - but that does only support (%s) string arguments, as opposed to the fuller range of replacements for RAISERROR/FORMATMESSAGE.

Comment: @Damien - Ah right I hadn't tested that. I just assumed it would work with things like `%d` - It doesn't seem to...

Comment: @Martin - still worth adding it as your own answer - if all the OP needs are %s, it's obviously the best answer.

Comment: This is exactly what I asked for. It doesn't quite suit my need, as `The float, double-, and single character types are not supported.`, and I will definitely need to display floats, but I don't think there's a built-in function to handle that, so... I'll try to work around with %s and convert. Accepted Answer.

Answer (score 15):

`PRINT` is just `RAISERROR` with a severity of 0. So you can use.

```
declare @name varchar(10)
set @name = 'George'

RAISERROR ('Hello %s.', 0, 1, 'George') WITH NOWAIT
```

Edit to store it into a variable you can use the `xp_sprintf` extended stored procedure.

```
declare @name varchar(10)
set @name = 'George'

DECLARE @ret varchar(500)
exec master..xp_sprintf @ret OUTPUT, 'Hello %s.', @name
PRINT @ret
```

Comment: I didn't know about `xp_sprintf`, and it almost answers my needs, except that `Currently, only the %s format argument is supported`. Bummer

Answer (score 6):

**As of SQL Server 2016**, [`formatmessage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/functions/formatmessage-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016#arguments) and [`raiserror`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/raiserror-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016#arguments) have been extended to allow them to work almost exactly like C's `printf` function. The first argument (that previously had to be an integer referring to a predefined message in `sys.messages`) can now be a `printf`-style format string:

```sql
select formatmessage(
    'This is a string %s and this is an integer %i%sand this is a string weirdly padded with spaces <<%7.3s>>%sand this is a hex representation of an integer %x',
    'foo',
    42,
    char(13) + char(10),
    'bar',
    char(13) + char(10),
    1337
);

/* output:
This is a string foo and this is an integer 42
and this is a string weirdly padded with spaces <<    bar>>
and this is a hex representation of an integer 539
*/
```

While `throw` [does not implicitly support this same formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016#differences-between-raiserror-and-throw), there is nothing stopping you from [using `formatmessage` together with this construct](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/language-elements/throw-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016#differences-between-raiserror-and-throw):

```sql
declare @errorMessage nvarchar(max) = formatmessage(
    'This is a string %s and this is an integer %i%sand this is a string weirdly padded with spaces <<%7.3s>>%sand this is a hex representation of an integer %x',
    'foo',
    42,
    char(13) + char(10),
    'bar',
    char(13) + char(10),
    1337
);

throw 50000, @errorMessage, 1;

/* output:
Msg 50000, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
This is a string foo and this is an integer 42
and this is a string weirdly padded with spaces <<    bar>>
and this is a hex representation of an integer 539
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple printf procedure using sql_variant data types. Unfortunately, it only works for SQL Server 2008 and above.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.printf
  @string nvarchar(max),
  @p1 sql_variant = null,
  @p2 sql_variant = null,
  @p3 sql_variant = null
AS
BEGIN
  declare @str nvarchar(200), @pos int, @type char(1)
  select @str = @string, @pos = 0

  --- @p1
  set @pos = CHARINDEX('%', @str, @pos)
  if @pos > 0 and substring(@str, @pos, 2) = '%%'
    set @str = stuff(@str, @pos, 2, coalesce(cast(@p1 as nvarchar(100)),'<null>')) 

  --- @p2
  set @pos = CHARINDEX('%', @str, @pos)
  if @pos > 0 and substring(@str, @pos, 2) = '%%'
    set @str = stuff(@str, @pos, 2, coalesce(cast(@p2 as nvarchar(100)),'<null>')) 

  --- @p3
  set @pos = CHARINDEX('%', @str, @pos)
  if @pos > 0 and substring(@str, @pos, 2) = '%%'
    set @str = stuff(@str, @pos, 2, coalesce(cast(@p3 as nvarchar(100)),'<null>')) 

  print @str
END
```

And here are sample invocations:

```
exec dbo.printf 'Hello %%', 'World'
exec dbo.printf 'Hello %%. Today is %% of the month', 'World', 28
declare @dd datetime; set @dd = getDate()
exec dbo.printf 'Hello %%. Today''s date is %%', 'World', @dd
```

Answer (score -3):

If you are looking to store some message in a variable, then **SET** should be enough for you to handle right? Unless I am not clear with the question.

```
SET @varcharVariable = 'message text';
```

Comment: I should have included an example. That was not my question.

Comment: @DonkeyMaster - you can still include the example in your question now ;)